# What is the difference between an anthology and a florilegium?

Tags: differences, nouns, latin, greek

Both words have origins meaning a gathering of flowers — one from Greek and one from Latin. Both appear to have the same definition. When should I use one rather than the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Florilegium** is simply a Late Latin [calque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) (a literal translation) of the Greek **anthology**. L *flōs/flōris* = Gk *ἄνθος* (*anthos*) "flower, blossom"; LL *legium* = Gk *λόγος* (*logos*), "subject matter".

In English we only use the Greek-derived term.

Answer (score 4):

*Anthology* is a relatively common word in contemporary English, but *florilegium* is not used. If you are writing a period piece, and you want to sound authentic, you could use *florilegium*, otherwise stick with *anthology*.

The [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows 1214 hits for [anthology](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x3.asp?xx=1&w11=anthology&r=) and 0 hits for florilegium.